# MSDeploy 3.0 Delegated Deployments

Tags: msdeploy, unauthorized

I've been trying to use `MSDeploy 2.1` to deploy projects to production via users who are not members of Domain Admin and are not the actual local server administrator - to no avail. I found several articles indicating MSDeploy 1, 2.0, and 2.1 had a bug that make it impossible to actually use the delegated deployment structure in MSDeploy.

**Does anyone know if MSDeploy 3.0 has solved that problem?**

Answer (score 1):

If by "delegated deployments" you are referring to the IIS delegation feature that allows non-admin deployments then, yes, MSDeploy 3 supports these. We are using them internally so I can confirm it works.